# unable to run the command in symfony

Tags: symfony

hey i am working on form using the  tutorial `http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html`
I have created a simple form  and configured the data in `parameter.ini` as follow:

```
database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_port     =
    database_name     = symfony
    database_user     = root
    database_password = 123456
```

when i am running in local host then i am getting the following error:

```
Connection refused
500 Internal Server Error - ConnectionException
```

why this is here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run the console commands to build your schema, create the database and tables?

The task

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

should run or give you a detailed error message on the console.

Comment: what exactly means updated?
You need to run the schema:update command every time you've changed the model

Comment: i have run the command to update schema but i m getting `connection refused ` error again

Comment: can you access the database with the same credentials from another application.. i.e. phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it looks like you haven't changed the password. This is the base config:

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     localhost
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
    database_password: root
```